# After upgrade no GUI

Tags: unity, upgrade

I am new to Ubuntu. I recently received a 'hand me down' machine at work, and decided to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04.1, in the hopes of solving some problems I was having.

The upgrade started fine, but after about 15 minutes the screen just went black. I went home, came back in the morning, and still a black screen.

I can access a terminal via 'ctrl alt F1' and navigate my account, but I have no GUI! 
What makes matters worse is that I have also lost access to the internet on this machine.

Any ideas on how to get Unity up and running, via file transfer through USB, on this machine?

Thanks!